# Redirect to site and jump to anchor

Tags: javascript, .htaccess

I try to redirect to a site and jump to an anchor on that site.

The anchor is `#tab-5`

I tried:

```
window.location.href = "/property/details?id=123#tab-5";
```

and

```
window.location.replace("/property/details?id=123#tab-5");
```

I also tried it with the full URL with domain name in it.

But the site does not reload. The URL is just replaced and it does not jump to the anchor.

---

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_name("xxx");
session_start();

include("app/Routes.php");
$template = checkRoute();

// Redirect to login page if user is not logged in
if (!$template && !isset($_SESSION["logged_in"])) {

    $bodyClass = "login";
    $template = "templates/php/login.php";

// Redirect to start page (list view) if user is logged in and no url is given
} else if (!$template) {

    header("Location: /property/list");
    exit;
}

// Redirect to template
if (file_exists($template)) {
    require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/master.php");
    exit;
}
```

**app/Routes.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * A .htaccess rule always calls the index.php if a file could not be found.
 * This method gets called by index.php and creates a path out of the request
 * url path and returns the affiliated template file if exist. If nothing is found,
 * then return "no-route" template.
 */
function checkRoute()
{
    $redirectUrl = (isset($_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"])) ? $_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"] : "";
    $_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"] = "";

    if (!empty($redirectUrl) && $redirectUrl !== "/login") {

        $templateRoot = "templates";
        $template = $templateRoot . "/php". $redirectUrl .".php";

        if ( ! file_exists($template)) {

            $template = "/". $template;

            if ( ! file_exists($template)) {
                $template = $templateRoot . "/html/no-route.html";
            }
        }

        if (file_exists($template)) {
            return $template;
        }
    }

    if (!empty($_SESSION["logged_in"])) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: All else being equal, that should work.

Comment: @Quentin Would url-rewrite cause this "issue"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by calling `window.location.reload()` just after it